# PIL - image.open returning wrong type

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm using PIL's image library to handle JPG files. From my understanding, calling PIL's `open()` function should return an object of type `Image`. However I'm having a problem where it returns an object of type `PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile`. Here's the code I'm running:

```
from PIL import Image
for filename in os.listdir(""):
    new_filename = filename
    if(filename[0] == '.'):
        new_filename = filename[2:]
    picture = Image.open(new_filename, 'r')
    print(type(picture))
```

Can somebody tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

According to the [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile), the `PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile` class is a subclass of the `PIL.Image.Image` class.

So your object is a specific kind of `Image` and can be used as an `Image` `=)`.

Comment: Easy to verify: `print(isinstance(picture, PIL.Image.Image))`.